# HTML anchor causing my php $_POST variable to be set as an array

Tags: php, html, forms, post, anchor

I have a php statement that draws an image on my webpage. When I click that webpage I ask in another php statement if $_POST isset and it always evalutes to true and prints out Array() when I perform a `print_r($_POST)`

The code I use to navigate to that page that shows the post as an empty array is...

```
echo 'Create a New Link<a href="createlink.php"><img src="images/add.png" width="5%" height="5%"/></a>';
```

What this does is writes out *Create a New Link* to the screen and then creates an anchor and finally displays an image. Then if the user clicks on the image it takes them to *createlink.php* and that is where I am for some reason having the $_POST variable set.

All the research I've done suggested that anchors use $_GET by default. I also do a test on $_GET to see if it is set and it is also set as an empty array.

Long story short, I don't want `isset($_POST)` to return true if I got to the page via an anchor link.

Comment: My bandaid was the function call empty so I do if(!empty($_POST))

Comment: `isset()` will always return `TRUE` for an empty array.  Use `empty($_POST)` to determine if it is empty.

Comment: Instead of testing `isset($_POST)`, test `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')`

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer can be found at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php):

> [$_POST] is a 'superglobal', or automatic global, variable. This simply means that it is available in all scopes throughout a script.

I think all you can do is check to see if it's empty.

Answer (score 3):

That's kind of impossible, just open any script in your browser (using get) and do `var_dump($_POST);` and the result is an empty array; it is always set.

You probably need to fix where you are checking if a post was made; a better way to check if a post request was made, is this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
```